# Entity Framework exception suddenly

Tags: c#, entity-framework, exception

I have this code in my backend:

```
using (var context = new Db_EnforcementEntities())
{
    try
    {
        DbContextHelper.SetContextConfig(context, false);
        VW_ENF_TviotOnePercentage[] test = context.VW_ENF_TviotOnePercentage.ToArray();
    }
}
```

where `VW_ENF_TviotOnePercentage` is a view which already exists in my `EDMX` file.
The above code worked perfectly up until several days ago, and I could fetch records which are identical to the records I could see in the database.

For some reason, when I get to the code now, I get an exception:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

The stack trace points to:

> at System.Object.GetType()
>   at System.Data.EntityKey.ValidateTypeOfKeyValue

What could go wrong in the database to cause this error?

Comment: You should use English language for title of the post.

Comment: Google translate says the title is similar to "Entity framework suddenly"

Comment: Tho OP forgot to `alt shift`.

Comment: @Inballta, maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33777283/3002584) would help.

Comment: I've saw this - I allraedy checked that no null values returns

Comment: Well, it's extremely likely that it does. Maybe you're not aware of what EF has inferred as key properties, which may be quite a lot. Check our EDMX file.